Granting sharepoint site permissions to an Application Registration using python and the graph api
I am trying to grant an application registration write permissions on a sharepoint site, so i can then use it to automate uploading files. I am using python.
I continually get an "invalid request".
So far i have double checked the following:

The access token is using the correct scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
the app registration used to create the access token has Sites.FullControl.All api permissions
the siteID is correct: myOrg.sharepoint.com,b63cg86c-ef1b-4ed0-b15a-46f668e76331,d891dc88-9c07-5hf6-a620-a85ca546t3a7
I have tried many itterations of the request body and header but all with the same issue.

My code is listed below. Its a function to get the token, a function to get the site id and a function to grant write permissions to the app registration.
I would appreciate any advice on this as it is starting to consume quite a lot of time.
#function to get access token to the graph api.
    def get_access_token_graph(Tenant_ID, Client_ID, Client_Secret):
    url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': Client_ID,
        'client_secret': Client_Secret,
        'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=data)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()['access_token']




def get_site_id(Access_Token, site_url):
    print("get_site_id")
    #    site_id_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_url.replace('https://', '').replace('/', ':')}"
    site_id_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_url}"

    headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {Access_Token}'
    'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
}
    site_response = requests.get(site_id_url, headers=headers)

    if site_response.status_code == 200:
        site_id = site_response.json().get('id')
        print(f"Site ID obtained: {site_id}")
    else:
        print(f"Error fetching site ID: {site_response.status_code} - {site_response.text}")

    return site_id



#function to grant write permissions to site for app registration
    def grant_permissions_2(access_token, site_id, app_id):
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/permissions"
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    payload = {
        "grantee": {
            "id": app_id,  # App registration client ID (grantor_appreg)
            "type": "Application"
        },
        "roles": ["write"]  # Assign appropriate roles like "owner", "write", etc.
        }

    response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

    print(f"Response from API: {response.json()}")

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Permissions granted successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")




   #calling above functions

TENANT_ID = '905041a7-a812-4634-ab43-30f9db212g14'
GRANTOR_CLIENT_ID = "27ef4773-433b-46dd-9859-795024293dbe"
GRANTOR_CLIENT_SECRET = "~a25T~8nbHcbBDauPsWh.eG2X95iHEJ4d3FgybdYc"
GRANTOR_OBJECT_ID = "6f8d2588-69ac-4a78-bd81-9bac9481e852"
SITE_URL = "myOrg.sharepoint.com:/sites/mySiteName"

Access_Token_graph = get_access_token_graph(TENANT_ID, GRANTOR_CLIENT_ID, GRANTOR_CLIENT_SECRET)

site_id = get_site_id(Access_Token_graph, SITE_URL)

grant_permissions_2(Access_Token_graph, site_id, GRANTOR_OBJECT_ID)


Checking the doc and the request body should contain grantedToIdentitiesV2 not grantee.
payload = {
    "grantedToIdentitiesV2": [{
      "application": {
        "id": app_id
      }
    }],
    "roles": ["write"]  # Assign appropriate roles like "owner", "write", etc.
    }

